# How can I create an Array that has its values as its type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

How can I write the following logic but without repeating the keys of the Array type?

```js
type UserFillable = [
  'first_name',
  'last_name',
  'email',
  'sector',
]

export default class User {
  public static readonly fillable: UserFillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'sector',
  ]
}
```

Another example would be...

```js
export default class User {
  public static readonly fillable = [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'sector',
  ] as [
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'sector',
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to infer the most specific type it can for the property you're initializing:

```
export default class User {
    public static readonly fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'sector',
    ] as const
}
```

This will automatically be the [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples) of [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) you're looking for:

```
// (property) User.fillable: readonly 
//   ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "sector"]
```

You probably don't need to define the `UserFillable` type anymore, but if you do, it would be better to do it in terms of `User.fillable` and not vice versa:

```
type UserFillable = typeof User.fillable;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=79#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAqgcFHAN4CwAUHI3GOgEaYCWOcBMqMXOFGCoEEAHaYAnnGQdM+dsDgBeOAG16TbXADkcqLwD641AFtgugDRadjXfmOmL123d3Azqea4Z295Dgw0L7aALpwhHA4ErxucAD0CXAAFGBQEGAUMFIAlKTkUAB0cgqoSgBcQiJikjLxSUzqAEQGTubAzVZwzY4wJh1dPZ7emEPNgcFQzWH0AL709DlZBRQAYvKKmMpqy8AQyKvFpVvAANz0jXtHG2VKqtWiEtIarRyG-c6d3b2En4M-EbycaTaAzIA)

Comment: Thank you very much! While this solution doesn't work for my use case(passing a `readonly` value is not possible as its expecting a `string[]` type), it definitely answered my question!

Comment: If you can't deal with `readonly` you could use a helper function to "promote" `readonly` to mutable values, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/GNl35w).